# Rails Active Storage image variant flipped upside down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

When rendering a rails active storage image variant as follows:

```rb
<%=image_tag(current_user.avatar.variant(resize_to_limit:[200, 200])) %>
```

The image gets flipped upside down. I have tried to remove the EXIF metadata by setting the `auto_orient` option as `true` like suggested [here](https://rubyflow.com/p/qqivs1-activestorage-variants-are-persisting-original-image-exif-metadata) without success.  This is definitely a rails bug because as soon as I remove the variant method, the original image displays correctly.

Note that I am uploading picture captured by iphone devices. [Here is the image used](https://easyupload.io/9fu47q).

*System configuration*:
Rails version: 6.1.5 /
Ruby version: 3.1.1p18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem by updating the backend the `image_processing` gem was using under the hood on my local machine (Apple Silicon, M1 chip). So, it was not really a rails issue, but something you should keep in mind when using Active storage variants.

Comment: How did you fix it? I am using the latest version of image_processing gem and still getting this issue